# Different FOR loop executions for the same pattern

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing two FOR loops to concatenate files using wildcards for their names.
I use a More +1 command (to skip the 1st line), a > symbol to feed a temporary file and
at the end, I Move /y the final file into a new extensionned file (renaming the file in fact).

I do not understand why the 1st loop need a Space bar hit to operate on each file 
whereas no need  hit for the 2nd loop for several files !!!

I've put an @ECHO OFF at the 1st line of the batch file.

Strange behaviour : I wrote an ECHO message in the 1st loop to have each command executed.
If I remove (or put this ECHO message as a comment), the loop doesn't work.

Any suggestions for that misfunctionning ?

Thank you.

Code samples :

```
for %%x in (.\req*.csv) do (
  echo %%x ... 
  more +1 "%%x" >tmpStock
  move /y tmpStock "%%x".sse)

for %%F in (req*.csv.sse) do (type "%%F" >>Stock.txt)
for %%F in (req*.csv.sse) do (DEL /Q "%%F")
```

Comment: May we see your code?

Comment: The 1st set of code lines (need Space bar hit...) :

rem Parcours des fichiers CSV Stocks en sautant la 1ere ligne
::
::
for %%x in (.\req*.csv) do (
    echo %%x ... 
::    for /f "skip=1 usebackq delims=" %%l in ("%%x") do (echo %%l >>tmpStock)
    more +1 "%%x" >tmpStock
    move /y tmpStock "%%x".sse
)
::
for %%F in (req*.csv.sse) do (type "%%F" >>Stock.txt)
for %%F in (req*.csv.sse) do (DEL /Q "%%F")
::
set file=Stock.txt
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo  %cnt%,lignes, dans %file% ! >>ComptageLignes.txt

Comment: How about editing your main question and putting that in a code block s'il vous plait?

Comment: pas de probleme.  Does my answer below help?  If not, try remarking out the `@echo off` at the top of your script and see if you can tell at what line the script pauses and waits for spacebar.

Comment: @rojo when waited via prompting with msg L'ajout de etc.
I've checked the Stock content...I read Suite 99%
That seems to be file length 
So I'll have the same problem for large file.

PS : the prompt stop at 65535 lines...

Comment: OK.  I can show you how to replace `more +1` with something else.  The line you wish to skip, the first line of each .csv file, is it similar in every .csv file?  Can you show me one or two examples of what the first line contains?  If so, then the solution is easy.  We'll just strip out unwanted content after the .csv files have been joined.  Otherwise, we'll have to use a for loop to loop through each line of each csv file to join them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this was the solution.

```
type req*.csv>tempfile
findstr /v /i /c:"unwanted text" tempfile>Stock.txt
del tempfile
```

*shrug*

Comment: I've tried the 2 solutions you've suggested...no improvement.
Your code works but still need space bar hit.
Could this caused by the length of the file ?

Comment: Not sure.  Does it pause at the `more` command?  If so, try replacing it with `echo; | more +1 "%%F" >>Stock.txt` and see whether piping an echo into it fixes it.  I just modified the script above to show this.  If that doesn't work, then you might have to use another `for` loop to dump the file into stock.txt.  Or it might be easier just to `type "%%F" >>stock1.txt` then use `findstr /v "lines_to_skip" stock1.txt >stock.txt` to strip out the lines you don't want.  There is a solution, in any case.  We'll keep experimenting until we find it.

Comment: more +1 code handles paging so not easy to use it inside batch file....

too bad !

Comment: Does that mean `echo; | more` didn't work?  What does the first line of each .csv file look like, the line you want to skip?  Is it similar in every .csv?

Comment: @rojo - You haven't addressed the fundamental problem. see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252262/1012053) for why redirected MORE can still pause.

Comment: @dbenham I haven't addressed the fundamental problem yet because I'm still waiting to see whether it'd make more sense to concatenate the csv files using `type *.csv>tempfile` without skipping lines, then use `findstr /v` or similar to strip out what's unwanted.  I need an answer from the OP before I can proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The MORE command normally pauses every time it displays a full screen's worth of information. But if the output is redirected or piped, then it does not pause after each screen. Unfortunately, it does not continue to print endlessly until file end. It will pause after ~64k lines (~65535) if the output is redirected or piped.

You could use a FOR /F loop to process all but the first line, but that is relatively slow.

I have written a simple hybrid JScript/Batch utility called SKIP.BAT that can be used to skip **n** lines from a file. It works as a filter, and is much faster than a pure batch FOR loop. Simply pipe data in, and it will skip the number of lines that you specify. The script can certainly be improved. For example, it does not have any error checking.

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @end /* Harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment

::************ Batch portion ***********
@echo off
cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" %*
exit /b 0

************* JScript portion **********/
for (var i=0; i<WScript.Arguments.Item(0); i++) {
  if (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) WScript.StdIn.ReadLine();
}
while (!WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream) {
  WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine());
}
```

As long as the above script is in your current directory, or else in your PATH, then your code can be reduced to:

```
@echo off
>Stock.txt (for %%F in (req*.csv) do type "%%F" | skip 1)
```

or, from the command line:

```
>Stock.txt (for %F in (req*.csv) do @type "%F" | skip 1)
```

Of course the entire solution could be written very easily in pure JScript or VBScript. Or the CSV concatenation could be integrated into one Hybrid script. But having a stand-alone SKIP utility is useful for batch development.

Comment: @rojo - Thanks :)  I find hybrid JScript/Batch to be a great way to write utility scripts. My favorite is REPL.BAT, a filter script that performs regex search and replace. It has *many* options built in, and it's amazing how many thorny batch problems are easily solved with the small utility. Just perform the following search on StackOverflow to see a list of varied questions that I solved with REPL.BAT: `user:1012053 REPL.BAT`. I included the REPL.BAT code in each of the answers.